# Python - Django - Heroku - ImportError - cannot import name 'fromshare' from 'socket'

Tags: python, django, heroku

I successfully deployed my app to heroku but now I am getting an error:

```
ImportError at /
cannot import name 'fromshare' from 'socket' (/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/socket.py)
```

Looks like it traces back to:

```
File "/app/users/forms.py" in <module>
  1. from socket import fromshare
```

I have looked everywhere I can online and have not seen anyone run into this. Any idea how I would fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Try removing `from socket import fromshare` from the file. Seeing how it's for a forms.py file, I don't think you need to import that module.

Answer (score 1):

[`socket.fromshare()`](https://docs.python.org/library/socket.html?highlight=socket#socket.fromshare) is only available on Windows. You won't be able to use it on Heroku since its dynos run Linux.

Without a lot more contect I can't recommend an alternative, but that's the root cause of your issue.